# django convert datetimefield to datefield with mysql backend

Tags: python, django, schema-migration

For my django app, I want to convert datetimefield to datefield. That resulting in an error :

```
 Date truncation for column ...
```

Can you please tell me how to do this ?

I have tried this:

I have written a datamigration before schemamigration that modifies values of datetimefield from datetime to date .

```
  obj.datetimefield = obj.datetimefield.date()
  obj.save()   --- error here.
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect that to work without a schemamigration?

You could add an extra field to your model, *then* run your code to copy it from the old field to the new field after some modification(s). *Then* you can delete the old field and *finally* rename the new field.

But honestly, you should have a look at [South](http://south.aeracode.org/), an excellent and common used tool for migrating django models.